# Eigen spectrum for block matrices having zero blocks below the secondary diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a block matrix $M$ of the form $M=\begin{bmatrix}[A]&[B]&[C]&[D]\\
[E]&[F]&[G]&0 \\ [H]&[J]&0&0\\
[K]&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}$, Any theoretical explanation to find the spectrum of $M$,

I have seen some results regarding the triangular block matrices, but here, all the blocks below the secondary diagonal are zero matrices, Any restrictions on the dimensions of the block entries? Is there any theoretical view on diagonalizability and similarity?